# index of the residue matched using pairwise2 in biopython

Tags: python, string, alignment, biopython, pairwise

I am interested in knowing the index of residues that match to a string using `pairwise2` in python.

For example I have two strings

```
A:' EEEEE      HHH     HHH             EEEEE'
```

and

```
B: 'EEE       EEEE       HHH'
```

using the following code:

```
from Bio import pairwise2
from Bio.pairwise2 import format_alignment

alignment = pairwise2.align.localdc(A,B, matrix,gap_function_1,gap_function_2)
```

One of the alignments that I get is :

```
EEE-------EE---      HHH     HHH             EEEEE
|||       ||   |||||||||
EEE       EEEE       HHH--------------------------
  Score=29.6
```

I want to get the indices of the match i.e the original positions of all the `Es`, `Hs` and `' '` from seq A that matched with seq B.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the first space in `A` is a typo? Otherwise the alignment would look different.

So, assuming:

```
A = 'EEEEE      HHH     HHH             EEEEE'
B = 'EEE       EEEE       HHH'

alignment = """EEE-------EE---      HHH     HHH             EEEEE
|||       ||   |||||||||
EEE       EEEE       HHH--------------------------
  Score=29.6"""
```

We could write a function `compare()`:

```
def compare(align, matches, original):
    result = []
    index = -1
    for char, match in zip(align, matches):
        if char == '-':
            index += 0
        else:
            index += 1
        if match == '|':
            assert original[index] == char
            result.append(index)
    return result
```

And then

```
align_A, matches, align_B, score = alignment.splitlines()
print(compare(align_A, matches, A))
```

Gives `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]`. A quick visual check confirms this: the first 14 characters of `A` are matched (5 `E`s, 6 spaces and 3 `H`s). And

```
print(compare(align_B, matches, B))
```

gives `[0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]`.